# Is the threshold value in `(model.predict(img) > 0.5).astype(np.int32)` (i.e) 0.5 is always fixed?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, predict

Should the threshold value always be 0.5 or can we adjust it according to our needs ?
I'm trying to detect Fire in an video by analyzing every frame. When i do this i get a lot of False Negatives when my threshold value of confidence (`confidence = model.predict(img)`) is o.5. So can i actually adjust the value so that i get better results or is it like cheating the model's prediction ?

This is my code:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
i = cv2.imread(img)
img = image.load_img(img,target_size=(250,250))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
img = img / 255

res = (model.predict(img) > 0.5).astype(np.int32)
if res == 0:
    print('Fire Detected')
else:
    print('No Fire Detected.')
```

Comment: You may adjust it by looking at ROC curve etc.

Answer (score 0):

You do not *have to* use threshold of 0.5. It is like that because typically classification models maximise accuracy, and for this metric 0.5 makes the most sense. However your problem might be different, maybe you care about precision more than recall? Then adjusting threshold is one of the ways of tuning your model (e.g. by plottinc ROC curve to see the possible tradeoffs). This is somewhat a naive way though, and one could also just ask oneself "what is my actual goal" before hand and maximise this metric from start, rather than maximise accuracy and then posthoc adjust threshold to adjust a different one. For example to tackle imbalance between positive/negative classes you can consider class weighting etc. (that will effectively maximise weighted accuracy).